# php não consegue copiar arquivo remoto, mas faz download pelo browser

Tags: php, file-get-contents, fopen

Olá. Este arquivo:

http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip

Consigo baixar pelo navegador, mas não consigo copiar direto para meu servidor usando PHP. Já testei todas as maneiras possíveis (copy(), file_gets_content(), fopen(), curl(), etc) e não há meio de fazer dar certo. Como devo fazer?

Comment: qual é o erro que acontece quando tenta no PHP?

Comment: Qual é o erro? Você precisa nos informar o sintomas para darmos o diagnóstico

Comment: Opa. Normalmente o erro retornado é:
Warning: copy(http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip): failed to open stream: Redirection limit reached, aborting in /home/megas028/public_html/teste/atualizar_resultados.php on line 43
failed to copy http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O que se passa é o seguinte:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como se pode ver pela imagem o servidor implementa um cookie (security=true) e deve redirecionar para o mesmo url, se tiver o cookie autoriza download, senão fica em loop de redirecionamento até 'ver' o cookie na requisição. Soponho que era isso que estava a faltar na sua requisição. Tente com `curl` o seguinte:

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, True);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: security=true"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip');
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1');
$return = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
file_put_contents('file.zip', $return);
```

Como pode ver desta maneira enviamos também o cookie, que era o necessário para que o servidor autoriza-se o download do ficheiro.

Aqui tem o a mesma requisição com [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$opts = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'=>"GET",
        'header' => array(
            'Cookie: security=true'."\r\n",
            'User-Agent' => "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.7; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1",
        )
    ),
);
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
file_put_contents('file.zip', file_get_contents('http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip', false, $context));
```

Comment: Resolvido! Valeu! Deixa eu estudar esse código direito, que perdi a manhã num monte de variedade e nada funcionou. Só esse!

Comment: @JoãoGurgel você preferiu usar o `curl`. Eu tava querendo descobrir porque as outras funções se comportam assim :\

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, acho que faltava mandar o cookie com a requisição, user agent (não tenho a certeza quanto a este ultimo mas pelo sim pelo não mais vale mandar)

Comment: @Miguel também estou desconfiando que seja isso. Parece que a url redireciona pra ela mesma.Talvez nesse meio processo haja uma verificação de alguma header que faltou.

Comment: Exato @WallaceMaxters , deve redirecionar para ela mesma e só autoriza quando vir o cookie

Comment: Exato @WallaceMaxters como eu desconfiava. Ora tente `$ curl -vL http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip"` ... Aí fica num loop de redirecionamento.... Depois faça `$ curl -vL http://www1.caixa.gov.br/loterias/_arquivos/loterias/D_megase.zip -b security=true` (envie o cookie com a requisição), aqui já tem acesso ao ficheiro

Answer (score 0):

A pergunta é antiga, mas a solução é nova (10/12/2019):

```
$VContext = stream_context_create(["http" => ['method' => 'GET', 'header' => ['Cookie: security=true'."\r\n", 'User-Agent' => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']]]]);

$VMegaSena = "http://loterias.caixa.gov.br/wps/portal/loterias/landing/megasena/!ut/p/a1/04_Sj9CPykssy0xPLMnMz0vMAfGjzOLNDH0MPAzcDbwMPI0sDBxNXAOMwrzCjA0sjIEKIoEKnN0dPUzMfQwMDEwsjAw8XZw8XMwtfQ0MPM2I02-AAzgaENIfrh-FqsQ9wNnUwNHfxcnSwBgIDUyhCvA5EawAjxsKckMjDDI9FQE-F4ca/dl5/d5/L2dBISEvZ0FBIS9nQSEh/pw/Z7_HGK818G0KO6H80AU71KG7J0072/res/id=buscaResultado";

$VResultado = @file_get_contents($VMegaSena, false, $VContext);

if ($VResultado !== false)
   $VResultado = json_decode($VResultado);

var_dump($VResultado);
```