# O que pode fazer com que o file_get_contents dê erro de "timeout"?

Tags: php, http, timeout

Fiz essa pergunta [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/177063/timeout-ao-tentar-utilizar-o-composer), mas dificilmente, por ser um problema que parece ser específico, a solução seria algo que seria algo genérico.

Porém me ocorreu nessa pergunta que fiz é que estou tendo problemas com a função `file_get_contents`.

Quando faço uma requisição através dela, sempre um erro é retornado:

```
file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/versions')
```

O retorno é:

`PHP warning:  file_get_contents(https://getcomposer.org/versions): failed to open stream: Connection timed out on line 1`

Porém, quando abro essa url no navegador, tudo funciona perfeitamente. Além do mais, se eu tentar fazer a requisição na url `https://www.google.com` ocorre o mesmo problema.

Porém o estranho é que não são todas as urls que geram esse problema.

Se eu fizer isso, funciona:

```
 file_get_contents('https://pt.stackoverflow.com/')
```

Pensei a princípio que o problema fosse com o `https` nas urls, mas não parece ser isso.

Se eu usar o `curl` funciona, mas não quero usá-lo, pois dependo exclusivamente do `file_get_contents` nessa ocasião.

O que pode fazer com o que o `file_get_contents` dê erro de timeout em algumas urls específicas, sendo que elas abrem normalmente pelo navegador?

---

**Observação**: Não gostaria de respostas como "usar o *curl* como solução alternativa", já que eu realmente preciso de usar *file_get_contents* para esse fim (além do mais, uma resposta com `curl` não responderia à minha pergunta).

---

Comment: Aqui rodou o `file_get_contents` sem problemas. Faça um `CURL`.

Comment: Cara, já falei. Veja o `max_execution_time`. E outro parâmetro também: `default_socket_timeout`.

Comment: Quanto ao teu exemplo específico `echo file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/versions');` funciona bem aqui e com o google a mesma coisa, mas eu estou a procurar algum serviço em que esse erro ocorra para ver se consigo responder à tua pergunta

Comment: Droga, eu descobri qual é o problema, a resposta poderá valer para as duas perguntas, kkkkkk

Comment: Aff, descobri nada!

Comment: Onde você está tentando usar esse código? Se for possível compartilha o trecho do código que está dando esse problema.

Comment: @CarlosFernandes independente do trecho, acontece isso.

Comment: Esse problema está ocorrendo no servidor local ou remoto?

Comment: Estou usando em Local, na linha de comando.

Comment: Emula uma maquina virtual e tentar utilizar o `file_get_contents`. Pelo que li aqui, há uma grande possibilidade de ser problema na rede ou na configuração do PHP.

Answer (score 1):

**Existem quatro possibilidades:**

1. Firewall ou qualquer software de bloqueio ou proxy configurados em sua máquina ou rede (um tanto quanto difícil de afirmar)
2. A partir da versão 5.6 o PHP passou a trabalhar totalmente diferente com SSL (http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php), exigindo configuração previa do `stream` para trabalhar melhor os certificados, quando necessários.

   Eu entendo que você disse que se acessar o `https://pt.stackoverflow.com` ele funciona, mas a questão é que o certificado **pode funcionar** bem para um site e talvez **para outro não**, isso não por falha sua necessariamente, mas talvez porque haja algum problema no certificado do `getcomposer` ou da sua máquina, de qualquer forma pode tirar a prova real assim:

   ```
   $arrContextOptions = array(
       'ssl' => array(
           'verify_peer' => false,
           'verify_peer_name' => false
       )
   );  

   $response = file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/versions', false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

   echo $response;
   ```

   Se funciona é problema nos certificados, talvez da sua máquina.
3. DNS usando no seu provedor de internet (vou chamar só de ISP pra ficar mais fácil) ou o próprio ISP, sim isso é complicado, por exemplo na empresa aonde trabalho o ISP falha em alguns site, até mesmo o site da empresa falha ou fica lento demais para abrir, mas no momento que uso o 4G o site carrega normalmente, isso não tem como ser resolvido localmente, até hoje tenho problemas aonde trabalho. Resumindo, pode ser que o servidor do composer conflite/falhe justamente com o teu ISP.

---

Claro que pessoalmente o problema possa ser realmente os certificados de conexão segura que falham justamente com o servidor do composer, inclusive já vi, tive problemas semelhantes, com o servidores do `npm`

### O que pode fazer para corrigir HTTPS

Pode baixar isto http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem, pode usar `wget`

```
$ wget http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem
```

E então apontar no PHP.INI assim (disponível desde php5.6):

```
openssl.cafile=/path/cacert.pem
```

Reinicie o Apache (se for apache).

> **Nota muito importante**
>
> Nas distribuições Linux geralmente o `php.ini` para CLI é diferente, o `composer` roda usando `CLI`, geralmente o php.ini do CLI está na pasta:
>
> ```
> /etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini
> ```
>
> Então você terá que editar tanto o `/etc/php/5.6/cli/php.ini` quanto o php.ini usado pelo Apache e em ambos adicionar `openssl.cafile=/path/cacert.pem`
>
> No Apache deve ser algo como `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini`
>
> Em versões mais antigas do Ubuntu as pastas como `/etc/php/5.4/`, `/etc/php/5.5/` e `/etc/php/5.6/` são trocadas por `/etc/php5/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$streamContext = stream_context_create(array(
    'http' => array(
        'method' => 'GET',
        'timeout' => 30
     )
));
```

Onde a chave `timeout` é em segundos.

Depois:

```
file_get_contents('https://getcomposer.org/versions', 0, $streamContext);
```

Comment: Estou testando aqui. Continua agarrado! O mais estranho é que a página é pequenininha...

Comment: Seu PHP é versão 6 ou superior ?

Comment: Tenta definir um User-Agent também @WallaceMaxters, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164682/php-n%C3%A3o-consegue-copiar-arquivo-remoto-mas-faz-download-pelo-browser

Comment: Sim, é o PHP 7. O estranho é que eu desconectei e conectei a internet, e a url voltou a ficar acessível. Agora eu quero voltar a ter o problema pra descobrir o que estava errado!

Comment: Eu limpei o cache de DNS e adicionei o certificado do composer lá (só que essa segunda não mudou muita coisa). Estou querendo descobrir como a rede pode afetar assim, a ponto de uma url funcionar e outra, não. Aqui não é bloqueado!

Comment: @WallaceMaxters, será problema de IP? Mudou o IP quando reconectou?

Comment: @PapaCharlie Não. O problema é resolvido quando eu reconecto. Mas quando eu rodo o composer (que faz uma porrada de requisições), volta a ficar "bloqueado" depois de um tempo.

Comment: Tem squid nessa sempre aí

Answer (score 0):

Comece por tentar incluir o `www`.

Pode tentar também :`ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 900);`(ou pelo script da resposta do Zooboomafoo) Aumentar o tempo limite que por padrão é `60 segundos`.

Verifique se o seu servidor pode acessar recursos externos se não há alguma restrição no firewall.

E podes tentar desativar o Ipv6 ou ainda configurar o contexto de Socket com o [bindto](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/context.socket.php#context.socket.bindto)

Se isso não resolver, use cURL..(zuera! ;))

Comment: O problema de aumentar o tempo é que não resolve. Ele fica mais tempo ainda tentando acessar a url, depois gera aquele Warning lá. Estou verificando se não é um problema na rede, pois depois de conectar e desconectar, voltou ao normal **(╯°□°)╯︵ ┻━┻**

Comment: Tentastes todas as opções que sugeri ?